Understanding Log Management on a Linux Server
I'm trying to get a better understanding of how log management works on a Linux server. When I install a Linux server, I notice that there are many log files and directories in /var/log.
My concern is about the potential for these log files to grow indefinitely until the server runs out of space.
What are the default mechanisms in place on a typical Linux server to prevent log files from growing indefinitely?
I know that logrotate is commonly used to manage log file growth, but is there a standard recommended practice for configuring logrotate on a server? Without proper configuration, it seems like the server could eventually run out of space.


is there a standard recommended practice for configuring logrotate on a server?

Not really.  It depends on your needs and your available disk space.
It is quite common, for instance, to configure logrotate for a service to rotate logs weekly and keep the last 4 logs (monthly retention).  However, if your service produces a lot of logged events, you might want to rotate logs daily.  You might need to keep logs longer for audit purposes, or delete them after a shorter time because you lack disk space.
On my personal webserver I rotate httpd logs monthly, and I've been keeping them for years, just because I have a lot of space available that I have no other use for.
You must also remember that the log size depends on the logging level.  Logs on a DEBUG level will grow up much faster than logs on ERROR (default) level.

Without proper configuration, it seems like the server could eventually run out of space.

Of course. This is why you should configure logrotate accordingly, allowing for some unexpected grow in logs (a lot of connections on your webserver, for instance, or a bunch of errors in the SMTP service). You should always set up some kind of free disk space monitoring on your servers.
Note that a good practice is to set up /var/log on a separate partition than /, to avoid freezing the server if the log directory fills up.
